# Client Certificate not passed or accepted by IIS using .NET 8, same code works in .NET 4.8

Tags: c#, iis, client-certificates, wcf-security, .net-8.0

The following wcf call works in a .NET Framework 4.8 console application, but does not in a .NET8 console application.

The service is hosted by an IIS 10. Inside the ssl settings we set client certificates to "Required". I'm using the `Systen.ServiceModel.Http` 4.10.3 package, but also tried the newest 8.0.0 package in my .NET8 console project. I also tried to target .NET6.

The IIS log says: `403 7 5 15`; so my assumption is, that the certificate isn't passed at all.

```
public static void Call()
{
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IExtendedParameterProvisioningPort>(new BasicHttpBinding
    {
        MaxBufferSize = 2147483647,
        MaxBufferPoolSize = 2147483647,
        MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647,
        SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0),
        ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0),
        Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
        {
            Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport,
            Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity()
            {
                ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate
            }
        }
    }, new EndpointAddress("https://example.de:1460/MyWcfService.svc"));

    channelFactory.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
        StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
        StoreName.My,
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
        "MY-THUMBPRINT");

    channelFactory.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication =
        new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication
        {
            CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        };

    var extendedParameterProvisioningPort = channelFactory.CreateChannel();

    var serviceInfoResponse = extendedParameterProvisioningPort.GetServiceInfo(new ServiceInfoRequest());
    Console.WriteLine(serviceInfoResponse.Version);
}
```

The exception I'm receiving is:

`The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'.`

Whats the issue here? Does .NET 6/8 not support client certificates yet, when it comes to `ChannelFactory` / WCF?

Comment: If it's a 403 then TLS must have been successful, otherwise the whole request would have failed and there would be no code. It looks like the server is expecting a different kind of authentication. Also if you are using `CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None` why are you bothering with TLS at all, that setting is totally insecure.

Comment: Its just an untrusted development ssl certificate and a test project, so I dont care about a ssl server certicate.

Comment: The thing that doesnt seem to work is the client certificate, and not the ssl certificate.

Comment: Check your IIS settings, have you followed all the steps https://serverfault.com/a/289116 Is the certificate issued for an Active Directory domain user with the correct mapping?

Comment: I can recheck them later. But the question that comes to my mind is: Why would it work with my .NET Framework 4.8 client, if its not configured correctly?

Comment: has the IIS site also been changed from 4.8 to 6?

Comment: I have a .NET8 client and a .NET Framework 4.8 client (consumers). The wcf service that is hosted in the IIS is always the same.

Comment: I think the problem might be that **ASP.NET Core** doesn't support **System.Servicemodel.web**. But **System.Servicemodel.http** has an 8.0 version that works for **ASP.NET Core**. Usually I think the solution to this problem is to upgrade the **WCF** project via **CoreWCF**. Then use **Corewcf.http** instead of **System.Servicemodel.http**.

Comment: @QIYou But the SERVER SITE is a normal .NET WCF 4.8 host, which is also third party more or less and I couldnt simply change it. Also, why would it work with a normal .NET 4.8 client and not a .NET 6 one, it has to be something on the client side, no?

Comment: In fact, **System.ServiceModel.http 8.0** can help **.net 8** receive WCF services. The 403 error you get should be a problem with the certificate. Since **.NET Core** can achieve the reception of client certificates by adding middleware in the application. Are you passing certificates through IIS like the .net framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered an issue where the default ChannelFactory in WCF uses the outdated HttpMessageHandler, which fails to pass certain certificates. After some investigation, I came across a helpful suggestion in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/5354#issuecomment-1814045659) post.

To address this problem, I implemented a solution using a new endpoint behavior. Credit goes to petersladek for this approach. Below is the implementation:

**First, define a new endpoint behavior (by petersladek):**

```
internal class CustomizeHttpHandlerEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
{
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        bindingParameters.Add(new Func<HttpClientHandler, HttpMessageHandler>(handler =>
        {
            var newHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
            // copy all properties set by WCF on it's handler (so we keep all configuration from wcf), see source
            // https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/main/src/System.ServiceModel.Http/src/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelFactory.cs#L272
            newHandler.AutomaticDecompression = handler.AutomaticDecompression;
            newHandler.Proxy = handler.Proxy;
            newHandler.UseProxy = handler.UseProxy;
            newHandler.UseCookies = handler.UseCookies;
            newHandler.CookieContainer = handler.CookieContainer;
            newHandler.PreAuthenticate = handler.PreAuthenticate;
            newHandler.Credentials = handler.Credentials;
            newHandler.SslOptions.EnabledSslProtocols = handler.SslProtocols;
            newHandler.SslOptions.ClientCertificates = handler.ClientCertificates;

            return newHandler;
        }));
    }

    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime) { }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher) { }

    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) { }
}
```

**Finally, to integrate this behavior, you need to register it with the ChannelFactory:**

```
channelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomizeHttpHandlerEndpointBehavior());
```